# Retrive Data from SQL based on values given in a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe in python "df" which is having vendor names. Also i have a sql database where i have vendor names as on of the feild. I want only those record that match the names given in the dataframe in python and which is between a particular given date. The codes i have used is as given below.

```
df= pd.read_excel('Vendor_Name.xlsx')
df['Vendor_Name']=df['Vendor_Name'].astype(str)
cnxn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"
                              "Server=server1;"
                              "Database=sales;"
                              "uid="+uid+";pwd="+pwd)
df1=pd.read_sql(("SELECT * FROM sales.dbo.allsales WHERE [Vendor Name] in '"+df+"'and tranDate >= '"+from_date+"' and tranDate <= '"+to_date+"'"),cnxn)
```

the error when I run the above code's last line is

```
The first argument to execute must be a string or unicode query.
```

Need help on understanding the error i am making in the above case.

Comment: In the last line, the entire DataFrame `df` is being concatenated with strings. You'll need to convert the `Vendor_Name` column to an appropriate string representation... Something like `"SELECT * FROM sales.dbo.allsales WHERE [Vendor Name] in '" + str(tuple(set(df['Vendor_Name']))) + [...]`

Comment: got the following error ``('07002', '[07002] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]COUNT field incorrect or syntax error (0) (SQLExecDirectW)')''

Comment: Try printing the exact string that is being passed to `read_sql` and visually inspecting it for syntax errors.

Comment: the issue is between the single quotes `'('abc',bnf','gf-df')' and trandate>='201901-01' and trandate<='2019-01-10'` is what i feel

Comment: a few vendor names are having a apostrophe (') like 'abc's' could this be the problem?

Comment: That could be! It's times like these I wish I had years more SQL experience :P